# Preimage of a point in differential geometry of surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, parametrization

I'm studying how to work with surfaces in differential geometry. The definition of a regular surface is the following one:

> A subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ is a regular surface if, for each $p\in S$, there exist a neighborhood $V\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ and a map $x:U\to V\cap S$ where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x$ is differentiable ($C^\infty$), an homeomorphism and its differential, $dx_q:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ injective.

My question is, each time I pick a point $p\in S\cap V$, and take its preimage, $x^{-1}(p)$, the set $x^{-1}(p)$ always consists in only one point? (since homeomorphisms are injective).

Comment: Yes, however notice that typically you are in a situation where you may have many parametrizations $x_\alpha:U_\alpha\to V\cap S$ at your disposal (which will satisfy a condition of compatibility, namely that $x_\alpha\circ x_\beta^{-1}:U_\beta\to U_\alpha$ is a diffeomorphism of open sets for all $\alpha,\beta$).

Comment: In that case, $x_\beta:U_\beta\to V'\cap S$, it is a possibility that $V'\neq V$, right?

Comment: To my comment, I think it's the general case.

Comment: I was focusing on the case where they had the same $V$ because that seemed your interest, but yes, usually you would formulate compatibility as $x_\alpha\circ x_\beta^{-1}:x_\beta[V_\alpha\cap V_\beta\cap S]\to x_\alpha[V_\alpha\cap V_\beta\cap S]$ being diffeomorphisms of open sets.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help!